# PHP 7.1 return type array of scalar

Tags: php

After recently moving to PHP 7.1, I would like to take advantage of the newer features, such as return types. Trying to return an array of scalar type, using phpstorm with 7.1 syntax, it appears returning an array or array of objects are the only list return types accepted.

```
/**
 * @return int[]
 */
public function findFoo(): int[] //syntax error
```

Is there a best practice for strictly defining return types of scalars, such as array of integers in this example?

Comment: You simply cannot define `array of anything` typehint.

Comment: https://skillvalue.com/en/quizzes/php

Comment: @u_mulder I was certain I had been able to return an array of objects on a prior method, but that's clearly incorrect. I see now that return type array is all that's available for lists. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

With the current array implementation, it would require checking all array elements at runtime, because the array itself contains no type information.

So use this:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function findFoo(): array //syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP array is "multi-typed" like the variables, you cannot define the type of an array.

That said, you must define your return type to just `array`:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function findFoo(): array
```

This will be a valid code.